# Meteor , using jquery sortable causes template to be unbound

Tags: jquery, events, dictionary, jquery-ui-sortable, meteor

I have a specific problem. I have built an application using meteor, that basically has some entities displayed in the main screen , and these entities are being handled by Jquery sortable. plugin. nothing in particular.

The behaviour i have , is the following. I have some events bound to every entity via the templating mechanism , so i have mouseenter, mouse over.

In the jquery plugin there is defined a placeholder.

Whenever i start drag and drop on any entity, and the placeholder moves from it's original location and the onChange event is triggered from jquery, the entity becomes unbound from the meteor events.

If however, i bind it through jquery , it doesn't happen. Does anyone has any idea what could be happening?

The issue can be replicated very simple. Use the sortable example from jQuery, extract the ul create part in a template .

```
<head>
    <title>auth</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
     <ul id="sortable">
{{>items}}
</ul>
</template>
<template name="item">
     {{#if clipped}}
     {{else}}
     {{/if}}    
 <div class="india">
      <li>Item {{this.id}}</li>
 </div>

 </template>

 <template name="items">
       {{#each items}}
            {{>item}}
       {{/each}}

      <div class="empty"/>
      <div class="empty"/>
      <div class="empty"/>
      <div class="empty"/>
      <div class="empty"/>
      <div class="empty"/>        
  </template>
```

The js file has

```
Template.hello.rendered = function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder:"place"
    });
};


Template.items.items = function () {
    var gigi = [];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
         gigi[i]={id:i};
    }
    return gigi;
}

Template.item.clipped=function(){
    return true;
};

Template.item.events({
    'mouseenter .india' : function () {
          console.log(this.id);
     }
});
```

and the css file:

```
.india{
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
}
.place{
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
 }
 .empty{
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;
 }
```

The fact that i have included the helper Template.item.clipped in the item template causes the item after move to loose all the events that were bound to it through the templating Template.item.events mechanism.

Comment: You may want to include some code :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the current jquery package added with `meteor add jquery` and the latest sortable from jquery ui. Everything works as expected including dragging. Could you specify which versions of jquery, jquery ui and meteor you're using?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I was unable to reproduce as well.

Comment: Unable to reproduce as well..

Comment: slight off-topic, but i've started to flag any old unanswered meteor questions as too broad. the "too localised" closing reason has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 0.8.0 has a completely rewritten template engine. Called Blaze. It should solve any of the jQuery issues that folks may come across.

Take a look at the docs http://docs.meteor.com and specifically the wiki page on using blaze. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze